# Why does `Finder` give me the incorrect size information of a folder?

Tags: finder

When I open the folder `Library/Containers` in `Finder`, I see the following information:

[image]

It gives me the impression, the folder `com.docker.docker` uses 64GB.

But when I run the following command

```
du -d 1 -m Library/Containers/ | sort -n
```

I get the output

```
2806    Library/Containers//com.docker.docker
```

So why do I get these very different results? Does this folder use 64GB, or just under 3GB?

In addition, there is a file `com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data//Docker.raw` for which `ls` tells me that file has a size of 64 GB (i.e. 63999836160 bytes). But the whole folder (according to `du`) occupies less than 3 GB. How can that be?

Answer (score 2):

This is because Docker uses [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

Finder is reporting the apparent size of the sparse file. Get Info shows the occupied size on disk.

[image: Docker Get Info showing size on disk different to the size of the folder]

Comment: But in the `com.docker.docker` folder is a file `Data/vms/0/data//Docker.raw` for which `ls -l` gives a size of 63999836160 bytes. 
I am very confused. The whole folder is only 3 GB, but it contains a 64 GB file, which is not 64GB? What is going on? Can I remove this file?